# Decompile lua from Unity Games

Tags: decompiler

I discovered that a Unity games have lua scripts. I tried to decompile lua using some tools but they are not working with lua from Unity Games. The header doesn't look the same so they seems encrypted. Any idea how to decrypt or decompile it?

Lua file example: http://www105.zippyshare.com/v/Gdy1wlRx/file.html

Comment: Have you tried this one https://github.com/viruscamp/luadec ?

Comment: Uhm, the Lua bytecode wasn't portable for quite some time. I think one of the recent versions attempted to introduce compatibility, though. So it'd depend on the Lua version. And then there could be the case of LuaJIT which uses an entirely different bytecode, but whose bytecode is portable. Aside from that any kind of extensions (and there's a plethora of patches against the vanilla Lua) could modify how the bytecode looks. What the numeric type is would also have an influence and so on ... I'm afraid there's no canned solution for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that Lua doesn't have a standard specification. Even a specific version might be implemented in various different ways. Lua is a scripting language, it doesn't care as much about what goes on under the hood as long as the car runs ya know? They may implement it differently.

Answer (score 1):

There is a decompiler program in this collection of tools that are fitted for the modification of a game called Mafia 2.

http://www.playground.ru/files/mafia_2_self_tools_nabor_utilit-83905/

Although a majority of the programs were specifically created for the game, the Lua Viewer/Decompiler indiscriminately assesses Lua files. This could work in your favor and it could also not; its failure could be attributed to versions of Lua that are incompatible with the program.